# Extract and store the loss and mAP values in database while training with model_main script in Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am working with Tensorflow object detection API for a custom dataset. I need to store loss and mAP values in my database for every epoch (based on the number of steps). I am using model_main.py for training but could not find any easy way (e.g. callbacks) to extract and store these values. I need real-time training and evaluation loss as well as mAP. How can I achieve this?

I know we can read these values from events files in training directory but parallelly running the method to read events file while training is going on does not seem efficient.